# MATLAB fitcSVM weight vector

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, svm, pattern-recognition

I am training a linear SVM classifier with the fitcsvm function in MATLAB:

```
     cvFolds = crossvalind('Kfold', labels, nrFolds);

          for i = 1:nrFolds                       % iterate through each fold

              testIdx = (cvFolds == i);            % indices of test instances
              trainIdx = ~testIdx;                 % indices training instances

              cl = fitcsvm(features(trainIdx,:), 
              labels(trainIdx),'KernelFunction',kernel,'Standardize',true,...
             'BoxConstraint',C,'ClassNames',[0,1], 'Solver', solver);

              [labelPred,scores] =  predict(cl, features(testIdx,:));
              eq = sum(labelPred==labels(testIdx));
              accuracy(i) = eq/numel(labels(testIdx));

          end
```

As visible from this part of code, the trained SVM model is stored in cl. Checking the model parameters in cl I do not see which parameters correspond to classifier weight - ie. the parameter for linear classifiers which reflects the importance of each feature.  **Which parameter represents the classification weights?** I see in the [MATLAB documentation](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcsvm.html) "The vector β contains the coefficients that define an orthogonal vector to the hyperplane" - is hence cl.beta representing the classification weights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in this [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/support-vector-machines-for-binary-classification.html), the equation of a `hyperplane` in `fitcsvm` is

```
                                 f(x)=x′β+b=0
```

And as you know, this equation shows following relationship:

```
                                 f(x)=w*x+b=0 or f(x)=x*w+b=0
```

So, β is equal to w (weights).